# Javascript function generators parameters

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am learning this feature from ES6(Function generators) and I am having difficulties to understand the following code :

```
function* HelloGen2() {
  var a = yield 100;
  var b = yield a + 100;

  console.log(b);
}

var gen2 = HelloGen2();

console.log(gen2.next());     // {value: 100, done: false}
console.log(gen2.next(500));  // {value: 600, done: false}
console.log(gen2.next(1000)); // {value: undefined, done: true}
```

Questions :

1 : In the first `gen2.next()` the line of code `var a = yield 100;` is called , is it set some value on the `var a` variable ?
   2:  In each gen2.next() only the line until the semicolon is executed ?
So for instance , in the second call `gen2.next(500)`  the line `console.log(b);` is not executed
3: i do not understand the last line `gen2.next(1000)`, how the b variable get the 1000 value ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When working with coroutines, it's important to understand, that although `yield` and `next` are different keywords, what they do is essentially the same thing. Imagine two coroutines as being connected by a two-way communication pipe. Both

```
 Y = yield X
```

and

```
 Y = next(X)
```

perform the same set of operations:

- write X to the pipe
- wait for the answer
- once the answer is there, read it from the pipe and assign it to Y
- proceed with the execution

Initially, the main program is in the active state, and the generator (`gen2` in your example) is waiting listening to the pipe. Now, when you call `next`, the main program writes a dummy value (`null`) to the pipe, thus waking up the generator. The generator executes `yield 100`, writes `100` to the pipe and waits. The main wakes up, reads `100` from the pipe, logs it and writes `500`. The generator wakes up, reads `500` into `a`, etc. Here's the complete flow:

```
    gen                   wait

main next()               null -> pipe
main                      wait

    gen                   pipe -> null
    gen yield 100         100 -> pipe
    gen                   wait

main                      pipe -> arg (100)
console.log(arg)          100
main next(500)            500 -> pipe
main                      wait

    gen a=                pipe -> a (500)
    gen yield a + 100     600 -> pipe
    gen                   wait

main                      pipe -> arg (600)
console.log(arg)          600
main next(1000)           pipe -> 1000
main                      wait

    gen b=                pipe -> b
    console.log(b)        1000
    gen (ended)           done -> pipe

main                      pipe -> arg (done)
console.log(arg)
main (ended)
```

Essentially, to understand generators, you have to remember that when you assign or somehow else use the result of `yield/next`, there's a pause between the right and the left (or "generate" and "use") parts. When you do

```
  var a = 5
```

this is executed immediately, while

```
 var a = yield 5
```

involves a pause between `=` and `yield`. This requires some mental gymnastics, very similar to `async` workflows, but with time you'll get used to that.

Comment: *"mental gymnastics"* really nice :-)

Answer (score 3):

The relationship between `yield x` and `generator.next(y)` is as follows:

- `generator.next(y)` **returns** `{value: x, done: false}`
- `yield x` **evaluates to** `y`

Additionally, a generator function doesn't begin execution when initially invoked. You can think of it as a constructor. Only after `generator.next()` is called does the actual function code execute until the first `yield` statement (or the function terminates).

In your example:

- `var gen2 = HelloGen2()` creates the generator, but nothing happnes.
- `gen2.next()` executes the function up to `yield 100` and then returns `{value: 100...}`.
- `gen2.next(500)` resumes function execution, firstly evaluating the `yield` statement to 500 (and immediately setting this value into `a`), and continue execution up to `yield a+100` and then returns `{value: 600...}`.
- `gen2.next(1000)` resumes function execution, firstly evaluating the `yield` statement to 1000 (and immediately setting this value into `b`), and continue execution up to termination and then returns `{value: undefined, done: true}`.

That last `undefined` is the result of the function *not* returning any value explicitly.

Comment: Given your first paragraph, `a` should be `undefined` (`.next()`), no?

Comment: @deceze `yield` precedes `.next()` (for matching pairs). the first `.next()` is not part of this pairing, and is used to "kick-off' the function (as explained). In fact, the argument of the first `.next()` call is ignored.

Comment: Yes, but your explanation suggests otherwise. You only explain the relationship between `x` and `y`, when there really should be one more `z` somewhere.

Comment: @deceze - I think the paragraph explains exactly that - the function is held until the first `.next()` - but if you think there's a better explanation (using `z`?) - feel free to suggest a modification.

Answer (score 2):

> Questions :
>
> 1. In the first `gen2.next()` the line of code `var a = yield 100;` is called, is it set some value on the `var a` variable?

Not at this time, with the next call of `gen2.next(500)` it gets the value of `500`. At the first call the value is still `undefined`.

> 2. In each gen2.next() only the line until the semicolon is executed?
>    So for instance, in the second call `gen2.next(500)` the line `console.log(b);` is not executed.

Right. The function stops directly after the last `yield` statement.

> 3. I do not understand the last line `gen2.next(1000)`, how the `b` variable get the 1000 value?

With the call of `next()`, the function continues at the last stop with the `yield` statement, the value is handed over and assigned to `b`.

The `console.log(b)`is performed and the function exits at the end and the result of the generator is set to `{ value: undefined, done: true }`.

```js
function* HelloGen2() {
    var a, b;
  
    console.log(a, b); // undefined undefined
    a = yield 100;
    console.log(a, b); //       500 undefined
    b = yield a + 100;

    console.log(b);    // 1000
}

var gen2 = HelloGen2();

console.log('#1');
console.log(gen2.next());     // { value: 100, done: false }
console.log('#2');
console.log(gen2.next(500));  // { value: 600, done: false }
console.log('#3');
console.log(gen2.next(1000)); // { value: undefined, done: true }
console.log('#4');
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```